# Is it a good idea to handle http exceptions globally in the ktor server?

Tags: kotlin, exception, ktor

```kotlin
fun Parameters.getString(name: String) =
    get(name) ?: throw BadRequestException("Missing or malformed $name")

fun <T> T?.ensureExist(name: String) =
    this ?: throw NotFoundException("No $name found"）
```

I made these to help me throw http exceptions and then use `StatusPages` to handle them together in one place. Then I noticed that `StatusPages` does not provide 409 Conflict exception. Of course this can be done with a custom http exception class, but I'm starting to wonder if this is the normal practice.

Comment: It's totally fine, and same technique is used to show redirect case in [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#redirect): there's a custom exception which is handled via `StatusPages`

Comment: Thanks. It is really strange that `StatusPages` only contain few http exceptions

Comment: @FishHawk if you mean that there are a few exceptions that are being transformed to HTTP status codes then this functionality is part of the default engine pipeline but not of the `StatusPages` plugin. Here you can see the conversion method https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/815f247050cd83e39dfd0a7454e795b206907977/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/engine/DefaultEnginePipeline.kt#L68.